# Barycentric interpolation polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to prove that if $$l_i(x) = \frac{w_{n+1}(x)}{(x - x_i)w_{n+1}'(x_i)} \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ w_{n+1}(x) = \left[ \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda_i}{(x-x_i)}\right] ^{-1} $$ then $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}l_i(x) = w_{n+1}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda_i}{(x-x_i)} = 1$$

I think we need to expand the sum and somehow terms will cancel leading you to 1 but I am not sure how to show this, any suggestions or hints is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}l_i(x) = 1$$

This follows from the fact that $w_{n+1}(x)$ is zero at all the $x_i$, therefore $l_i(x)$ is zero at all the $x_j$ for $j\neq i$ while at $x = x_i$ it is equal to 1 (after you remove the removable singularity). This means that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}l_i(x)$ is equal to 1 at all the $x_i$. Because the $l_i(x)$ are nth degree polynomials, it follows that the summation is a constant equal to 1.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, is there a way of proving it formally?